# In Electron, using "typeof" causes TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: node.js, electron

I got a doozie here.  In [Electron's](https://electronjs.org/) main process, I require in the function below to setup event handlers with [ipcMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main). This keeps the main.js file a little more streamlined. All went swimmingly until I wrote some validation code to ensure that the user passes in an object. I use `typeof` all the time for this purpose, and never have I had an issue. But in Electron I am getting:

> A JavaScript error occurred in the main process - TypeError: Cannot
>   assign to read only property 'exports' of object '# '

The code:

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron');

function ipcSetup() {

  ipcMain.on('123', function(event, arg) {

    // this blows chunks...
    if(arg && typeof arg === 'object') {
      console.log(`All good....`);
    }

    // and if you comment that out, this use of "typeof" does the same thing
    console.log(typeof arg);

    // and to eliminate 'arg' as the issue...
    let a = 1;
    console.log(typeof a); // expect 'number', get Exception

  });

}

module.exports = ipcSetup;
```

I didn't know if Electron is using `Object.defineProperty` to make `arg` read only, but `typeof` is not making an assignment here anyway, and I eliminated `arg` so this error makes no sense. Environment is Electron 1.8.4 on Node 8.2.1 using [electron-vue](https://simulatedgreg.gitbooks.io/electron-vue/en/)

Comment: The `typeof` syntax works fine in the main thread. This must be an issue with context or how the module is imported perhaps. Still working towards an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing that module in another module that uses ES6 import/export syntax, using typeof apparently causes this. I think this is because **webpack** doesn't support mixing the two syntaxes. But it is quite funny that it would work fine if you didn't use the typeof operator...